# Does matter shrink due to energy radiation and does it have anything to do with dark matter and dark energy?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, cosmology, dark-matter, dark-energy

Is matter shrinking? Is shrinking the cause of concentrated dark matter that makes up matter moving from concentration to unconcentration. Does dark energy and expansion of the universe come from this process?

Comment: What does it mean for matter to shrink, do you think?

Comment: All matter is subject to a half life. And no, dark matter/energy is completely unrelated.